# Where is class definition for org/datanucleus/store/mapped/scostore/JoinSetStore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to run Data Nucleus+JDO+google cloud sql.  However I get a class not found for org/datanucleus/store/mapped/scostore/JoinSetStore.  What Jar contains that?

```
  com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.example.e_math.NoteEndpoint.getPersistenceManager(NoteEndpoint.java:162)
    at com.example.e_math.NoteEndpoint.insertNote(NoteEndpoint.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:239)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:161)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:466)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:473)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:470)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1093)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at com.example.e_math.PMF.<clinit>(PMF.java:8)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-a0911210062beea1(Request.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/store/mapped/scostore/JoinSetStore
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-a0911210062beea1(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:269)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:680)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:476)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:288)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:660)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.JoinSetStore
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-a0911210062beea1(Request.java)
    ... 53 more
```

Here is my war\web-inf\lib
[image]

and jdoconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/ 
jdoconfig"> 

   <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional"> 
       <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" 
           value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/> 
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" 
value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/> 
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" 
value="jdbc:google:rdbms://emath-project:myproject/myproject"/> 
<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName"
    value="root"/>

       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" 
value="true"/> 
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" 
value="true"/> 
       <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/> 

       <property name="datanucleus.metadata.validate" value="false"/> 
       <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/> 
       <property name="datanucleus.validateTables" value="true"/> 
       <property name="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false"/> 
       <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" 
value="true"/> 
   </persistence-manager-factory> 
</jdoconfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you got *datanucleus-rdbms-2.1.0-m3* in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: I downloaded it to try and fix the problem I think.  Removing it gives me a org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"

Comment: indeed but its a daft idea to include it. Regarding the error "jdbc:google:rdbms://emath-project:myproject/myproject" isn't a real JDBC driver URL, just some weird Google wrapper and DataNucleus uses the URL provided to work out what type of RDBMS it is. You could easily enough specify the persistence property "datanucleus.rdbms.datastoreAdapterClassName" to the RDBMS adapter appropriate for your datastore.

Comment: Ok I will take a  look, should datanucleus-rdbms 3.13 be in there because I downloaded that too, and should datanucleus versions match my datanucleus-appengine which is 2.1.2?  Or does not matter?

Comment: "datanucleus-appengine" is not provided by "DataNucleus project", they use whatever version numbers they want, and obviously that is nothing to do with Cloud SQL ... it is for GAE/Datastore (aka BigTable) ... so likely can be removed.