# Google Cloud endpoint and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a Google Cloud SQL from a Google Cloud Endpoint API. I am using Java Data Objects and in my 'jdoconfig.xml', I have added the following entries

I have added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 and datanucleus-rdbms-1.1.5 jars in my classpath. Have also added them in lib/Impl folder of the appengine sdk.

But everytime I am getting  a NoClassDeffoundError. A little help will be much appreciated!

Comment: There is not enough detail here. Please provide exception details.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/store/mapped/scostore/JoinSetStore. Also I am getting this warning --- org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry registerExtensions: Extension Point "org.datanucleus.store_datastoremapping" not registered, but plugin "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" defined in file:/base/data/home/apps/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-1.1.5.jar refers to it.

Comment: @saiyr pasted the log

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612916/where-is-class-definition-for-org-datanucleus-store-mapped-scostore-joinsetstore) is related.

Comment: Just an update. i have left this approach and am following django rest framework with Google cloud Sql. And it works!